# Access cross GCP projects with one shared service account credentials

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, service-accounts

I have two Google Cloud Platform (GCP) projects. Let's say Project A and B. I created one service account in Project A and generated a JSON key. I want to access the services of Project B using the same JSON key.

A sample JSON key is provided below.

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "PROJECT_ID",
  "private_key_id": "KEY_ID",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nPRIVATE_KEY\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL",
  "client_id": "CLIENT_ID",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL"
}
```

Since this key contains the project id, can I can use this key to access different project?

I checked some questions on Stack Overflow like [1] and [2].

[1] - *[Multi-Project(Account) service account in GCP](https://articles.wesionary.team/multi-project-account-service-account-in-gcp-ba8f8821347e)*

[2] - *[Creating a Cross Project (or Account) Service Account in GCP Step-by-Step](https://www.cloudquery.io/blog/creating-cross-project-service-accounts-in-gcp)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [article1](https://articles.wesionary.team/multi-project-account-service-account-in-gcp-ba8f8821347e) & [article2](https://www.cloudquery.io/blog/creating-cross-project-service-accounts-in-gcp) mentioned by you can be used as a reference to access cross GCP projects with one shared service account.Also make sure to follow the below recommendation.

As per the **[official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/attach-service-accounts#enabling-cross-project)**, to enable service accounts to be attached **across projects**, the following constraints in the organization policy for the project where your service accounts are located are recommended.

Ensure that the `iam.disableCrossProjectServiceAccountUsage` boolean constraint is **not enforced** for the project. This boolean constraint controls whether you can attach a service account to a resource in another project. The constraint is **enforced** by **default**.

Ensure that the `iam.restrictCrossProjectServiceAccountLienRemoval` boolean constraint is **enforced** for the project. This boolean constraint ensures that principals can remove the project lien only if they have the `resourcemanager.projects.updateLiens` permission at the organization level. If this constraint is **not enforced**, principals can remove the project lien.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use one service account to operate within multiple GCP projects.

Basically, the administrator/owner of the project should grant proper permissions to your service account.

So, let's assume that you have service account `SA_A` created in `PROJECT_A` and another `PROJECT_B` without service account. You have to generate json keys in the `PROJECT_A` only. Let's say, that you require permission `P` in both project - just add the permission `P` to te service account `SA_A` in both projects `PROJECT_A` and `PROJECT_B`.

It's so simple as is.

Comment: Thanks, Do we need to disable iam.disableCrossProjectServiceAccountUsage policy to use this?
If the server want to access Google Play Integrity API enabled in more than one projects then is it enough to have one shared account?

Comment: No idea about CrossProject iam option, let's play and try.